# Salinic bridges in voltaic cells

Tags: electrochemistry, electricity

I'm doing a study a study on voltaic cells.
I've been working with them for a while and one of the questions that I've had is how does the salt bridge affect the cell. I mean, I know it allows ions to move and that it'a a basic component of the pill. But, does its' concentration affect the voltage of the cell itself?
Thank you.

Comment: A n ideal salt bridge just eliminates liquid-liquid junction potential without affecting the equilibrium of the cell. A non ideal salt bridge changes the observed voltage depending on the relative mobilities of the ions in the salt bridge solution.

Answer (score 1):

A cell has an internal ohmic-equivalent resistance.  The salt bridge is a resistive path for the flow of ions.  Ions, plus their hydration shells and possible coordination shells, have low drift velocities through a medium.  The salt bridge can constrain the ion current of the cell and its material equilibrium rate.  A poor salt bridge by length, diameter, concentration, and permeability will increasingly adversely affect a cell's current and voltage as discharge rate increases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it affects the voltage of the cell as : 
E°(cell)= E°(red,cathode) - E°(red,anode) 
so it doesn't depend on the salt bridge !

Comment: Theoretically it does not, although many factors ensure the observed voltage is lower than the theoretical voltage including the resistance of the salt bridge.